# signTypedData vs sign(TypedDataEncoder.hash)

Tags: ethers.js

I am using latest v5 ethersjs

`const signature = await signer._signTypedData(...)`

and

`const signature2 = await signer.signMessage(ethers.utils.arrayify(_TypedDataEncoder.hash(...))`

return different results, what am I doing wrong?

Stack trace below...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

_signTypedData does not add "\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n", but the signMessage function automatically adds a prefix to the data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,
And how do I sign the message in ethersjs not using signer.signMessage?
Also as I see it hits the RPC node, I want to eliminate that